# Amazon EC2 micro instance not responding

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a couple of micro instances that have been working fine for weeks. Both are running WordPress blogs. In the last 24 hours one of them has stopped. I can't ssh in even after a reboot. The other instance is working fine.

```
ssh: connect to host ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

There in nothing obvious in the log that looks like a problem. The last few lines are:

```
cloud-init:  runcmd[  OK  ]
Mounting other filesystems:  [  OK  ]
Retrigger failed udev events[  OK  ]
Generating SSH1 RSA host key: [  OK  ]
Starting sshd: [  OK  ]
Starting ntpd: [  OK  ]
Starting sendmail: [  OK  ]
Starting sm-client: [  OK  ]
Starting crond: [  OK  ]
[  OK  ]
Starting atd: [  OK  ]
Starting yum-updatesd: [  OK  ]
Running cloud-init user-scripts (none found)[  OK  ]
Amazon Linux AMI release 2011.02.1.1 (beta)
Kernel 2.6.35.11-83.9.amzn1.i686 on an i686
ip-xx-xxx-xx-xx login:
```

The management console states that everything is running and normal.
I use the same security group and .pem file for both instances.

I suspect that this instance has been getting more traffic than the other one. Is there anyway that the micro instance could run out of memory and just stop responding? What could be going wrong?

[Here is a screen shot of the Monitoring panel](http://cl.ly/2W1a3V1G0y1Z030L0W06)

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several possibilities, but the two most likely are:

1. High load on the host that your Micro instance is running on - Micro instances get a small slice of resources anyway, and get scaled back quite harshly when the host is under load.
2. A fault has occurred on the host which is impacting VM responsiveness - this is actually relatively common, and can exhibit the type of behaviour you're seeing.

In either case, the quickest solution is to nuke the instance and restart it - you'll likely get a new instance on a different host, which may be less stressed or less broken. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After a few hours I was able to ssh in again and restart httpd and mysqld. Not sure what the problem was. Do you mean terminate the instance and start another one? Can I save the data on there if I do this?

Comment: I did indeed mean that you should terminate the problem instance and create a new one - *HOWEVER BE AWARE* that any data held only on the instance ephemeral store will be *LOST* when you terminate. If you wish to keep any data, move it to an attached EBS volume - this volume is persistent and will not be destroyed when you kill the instance. You can then attach it to the new instance when it starts up. Please read-up on instance and ephemeral storage lifespans if you are unsure of what you're doing, and make sure your data is backed-up if important to you.

Comment: thanks Jonners. Apparently it had an underlying hardware issue and had to be rebooted.

Comment: Fast-forward to 2013: if the instance was launched from an EBS-backed AMI, which is typical, then you could simply stop & restart the EC2 instance (rather than terminate and re-launch).  This would likely cause it to restart on new physical hardware, and your instance would be intact.  Also note that t1.micros are not really appropriate for any kind of production workload.

Answer (score 16):

I've seen micro instances lock up for several minutes due to the CPU "stealing" that occurs when you use too much CPU.  This is unique to the micro instance.  I blogged an example of this (including video) at http://gregsramblings.com/2011/02/07/amazon-ec2-micro-instance-cpu-steal/.

You can move your instance to new resources simply by doing a full STOP and then a START.  This will assign it to new hardware and will assign a new IP address (don't forget to re-associate your elastic IP!).   A host reboot will not accomplish this.  It needs to be stopped via the EC2 console.  Terminating it is not necessary.

Comment: This worked for me. There was an option in the ec2 console to reboot the instance and I didn't need to re-associate the IP.

Comment: well thanks.. because of this i just lost my whole site.. I clicked Stop.... then after it stopped i click start.. and then it went right into Termination mode and now i don't have a site anymore. no volumes or backups apparently either..

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted the instance and it started working again. [See the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNEzK.png)