# EC2 Instance Requires Daily Restart

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running a Wordpress blog on an AWS t2.micro EC2 instance running the AWS Linux. However most days I wake to an email saying that my blog is offline. When this happens I cannot SSH into the EC2 instance, however on the AWS dashboard it is shown as being online and none of the metrics look too suspicious.
[image: Cloudwatch metrics 1]
[image: Cloudwatch metrics 2]

[image: CPU Utilisation]

The time I was notified about the blog being down was just after the start of the first plateau on the CPU Utilization graph - 4:31am.

A restart from the AWS control panel/app fixes things for a day or two, however I would like to have a more permanent fix.

Can anyone suggest any changes I can make to my instance to get it running more reliably?

[Edit - February 2018]
This has started happening again, after being fine for a few months. Each morning this week I have woken up to an alert that my blog offline - a reboot of the server brings it back online. This morning I was able to investigate it and was able to SSH in. Running `top` gave the following (I noticed the lack of http/mysqld):
[image: Top screenshot]

My CloudWatch metrics for the last 72 hours are:
[image: Cloudwatch metrics]

The bigger spikes are where I rebooted the instance. As you can see from the CPU balance, although there are spikes, they aren't huge spikes, as the CPU Credit Balance metric barely dips.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11928451/1562662 This could be one possible reason, check the `CPUCreditBalance` in CloudWatch.  t2 micro is useful for dev/test load, for production load use `m instance family`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm pretty sure it isn't that, I have a alarm set to warn me when I am low on credits. I have added the metrics for credits to the question, to have the complete set. My maximum daily views are under 50, so I should be able to get away with a t2.micro, these problems don't seem to be related to "busier" periods.

Comment: Have you checked the console output (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-console.html) if something noteworthy is in there?

Comment: Looks like your incoming traffic goes up when the problem starts.

Comment: You might monitor your instance's memory.  The EC2 infrastructure can't see that info, but there is an official/unofficial [script](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html) for adding this to CloudWatch.  The docs refer to it as an "example" because it is officially not supported/guaranteed by AWS but it is perfectly usable.  EC2 instances are fundamentally stable.  Something on your machine is maxing the memory, most likely Apache if you are running it.  Also `sudo egrep -i 'kernel|oom' /var/log/syslog` (or `/var/log/messages`).

Comment: @Dunedan Nothing noteworthy in the console output - thank you for letting me know about it though!

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot is right, the first thing to do is monitor the memory use.

Answer (score 0):

As this question has had so many views, I thought I would post about the workaround I have used to overcome this issue.

I still do not know why my blog goes offline, but knowing that rebooting the EC2 instance recovered it, I decided to automate that reboot.

There are three parts to this solution:

1. Detect the "blog offline" email from Jetpack and send it to AWS. I created a rule on my Gmail to handle this, forwarding the email to an address monitored by AWS SES.
2. The SNS triggers an AWS Lambda function to run.
3. The Lambda function reboots the EC2 instance.

Now I usually get a "blog back online" email within a few minutes of the original "blog offline" email.